# document.getElementById('').display=block not working

Tags: javascript

In the following document, when someone clicks radios (which are in a table) function StOptnClkd is called. It accomplishes everything but the most important thing. There are two elements that need to switch from being diplayed to not displayed- namely, - AmxDisc and stOptnsTbl. These elements are displayed based on the selection on the radio buttons and check boxes.Please help me. I am a newbie trying to learn to code

I have attached the following code

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function StOptnClkd(clicked_id)
    {
        //alert(clicked_id)
        var strvid = clicked_id;
        var StVal = document.getElementById(strvid).value;
        document.getElementById("STtypCptrd").checked="Checked";
        document.getElementById("cntctpe").innerHTML=StVal;
        document.getElementById('Autonote').value = document.getElementById('Autonote').value+"Spke to: " + StVal; + ", ";
        document.getElementById("AmxDisc").display="Block" // this doesnt show
        document.getElementById("stOptnsTbl").display="None"  // this doesnt get hidden
    }
    </script>


<table  id="stOptnsTbl" border cellspacing="50px" style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;float: left; display: none">
    <tr>        <!--All Party Options-->
        <td width="110px" id ="CMOptn" class="stOptions">
    <label class="container1" style="float:Left"><Strong>  CM</Strong>
     <input id= "optstCM" type="radio" value ="CM" Name="stPrtysel" onclick="StOptnClkd(this.id)">
     <span class="checkmark1"></span>
    </label>    
    </td>
    <td width="110px" id ="UTPOptn" class="stOptions">
        <label id="lblUPT" class="container1" style="float:Left"><Strong> UTP</Strong>
     <input id= "optUTP" type="radio" value ="UTP" Name="stPrtysel" checked="checked" onclick="StOptnClkd(this.id)" >
     <span class="checkmark1"></span>
    </label>    
    </td>
    <td width="110px" id ="SPOptn" class="stOptions">
        <label id="lblSP" class="container1" style="float:Left;"><Strong> SP    </Strong>
     <input id= "optSP" type="radio" value ="SP" Name="stPrtysel" onclick="StOptnClkd(this.id)" >
     <span class="checkmark1"></span>
    </label>
    </td>
    <td width="110px"  id ="SUPOptn" class="stOptions">
        <label id="lblSUP" class="container1" style="float:Left;"><Strong> SUP    </Strong>
     <input id= "optSUP" type="radio" value ="SUP" Name="stPrtysel"onclick="StOptnClkd(this.id)" >
     <span class="checkmark1"></span>
    </label>
    </td>
    <td width="110px" id ="ATPOptn" class="stOptions">
        <label id="lblATP" class="container1" style="float:Left;"><Strong> ATP    </Strong>
     <input id= "optATP" type="radio" value ="ATP" Name="stPrtysel"onclick="StOptnClkd(this.id)" >
     <span class="checkmark1"></span>
    </label>
    </td>
    <td width="110px" id ="ATTOptn" class="stOptions">
        <label id="lblATT" class="container1" style="float:Left;"><Strong> ATT   </Strong>
     <input id= "optATT" type="radio" value ="AM" Name="stPrtysel" onclick="StOptnClkd(this.id)">
     <span class="checkmark1"></span>
    </label>
    </td>
    <td width="110px" id ="AMOptn" class="stOptions">
        <label id="lblAM" class="container1" style="float:Left;"><Strong> AM    </Strong>
     <input id= "optAM" type="radio" value ="AM" Name="stPrtysel" onclick="StOptnClkd(this.id)" >
     <span class="checkmark1"></span>
    </label>
    </td>








</span>
</span>
</tr>
</table>
<span width="100%" id="AmxDisc" style="display:none;">
     has referred your  account to  for resolution.
```

EDIT: IT IS THERE, coudnt post all the code here, If you guys need the whole code tell me, I can mail it. or find a way to put it here

Edit2: I did the style.display change. It still doesnt do it. IN console, it shows error saying unexpected identfier at that line

Comment: There is no element with the id `AmxDisc` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("AmxDisc").style.display="block"

Comment: You need to modify style attribute, because display is part of style.

Comment: I did the style.display change. It still doesnt do it. IN console, it shows error saying unexpected identfier at that line